# Return part of the text using Regex and C#

Tags: c#, regex

I was trying to find a certain part of the text having a specific keyword. I did it but I am thinking there might be a better way to do it.

Here is my code,

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return String containing the search word
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strInput">Raw Input</param>
    /// <param name="searchWord">Search Word</param>
    /// <param name="minLength">Output Text Length</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static String StringHavingSearchPattern(String strInput, String searchWord, Int32 minLength)
    {
        //considering the return string empty
        String rtn = String.Empty;
        //
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strInput))
        {
            return rtn;
        }
        // consider the raw input as return;
        //rtn = strInput;
        int length = strInput.Length;

        //if the rawinput length is greater||equal than/to the min length
        if (length >= minLength)
        {
            int currentSearchIndex = -1;
            searchWord = String.Format(@"{0}", searchWord);
            //currentSearchIndex = strInput.IndexOf(searchWord,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            Match m = Regex.Match(strInput, searchWord, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                currentSearchIndex = m.Index;
                if (currentSearchIndex >= 0)
                {
                    if (currentSearchIndex > 9)
                    {
                        if ((length - currentSearchIndex - 1) >= minLength)
                        {
                            rtn = strInput.Substring((currentSearchIndex - 9), minLength);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rtn = strInput.Substring((currentSearchIndex - 9), length - currentSearchIndex - 1);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rtn = strInput.Substring(0, minLength);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    rtn = strInput.Substring(0, minLength);
                }
            }
        }
        rtn = Regex.Replace(rtn, searchWord, String.Format("<span style='color:yellow;background-color:blue;'>{0}</span>", searchWord), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

        //rtn = rtn.Replace(searchWord, String.Format("<span style='color:yellow;background-color:blue;'>{0}</span>", searchWord));
        return rtn;
    }
```

Looking for your kind suggestions to improve it.

Comment: why do you need `minLength`...

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: @Anirudha, Would like to return the text containing the keyword.The length of the text is the minLength.

Comment: Its not very clear what you are trying to do with If conditions there "if (currentSearchIndex >= 0)" and "if (currentSearchIndex > 9)" and  "if ((length - currentSearchIndex - 1) >= minLength)". If you add some comments in the code, it will help.

Comment: @MilindThakkar, I would like to return 10 Characters before the keyword + Keyword + and the remaining text. The total length will be the minLength.

Comment: You could provide sample of inputs & outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hunch was right; you can use a single, simple regular expression to achieve this:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(strInput, "(.{0," + minLength.ToString() + "}" + searchWord + ".*)", ...
```

This will create, for example for `searchWord` "keyword" and `minLength` 10, the following regex,

```
(.{0,10}keyword.*)
```

which means, "Capture up to 10 characters followed by 'keyword' and the remainder of the text." Then, you can grab the captured group:

```
m.Groups[1].Value
```

Note that the case where there are less than `minLength` characters before the search term is covered.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tired but it does not give proper result. From the above expression, would it be ((.{,10}strInput.*) instead of (.{,10}keyword.*)?

Comment: Oops, yes, I meant ``searchWord``. Edited solution. Does it work after that change?

Comment: If I do .{10}keyword.* instead of (.{,10}keyword.*) ,then it works.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the ``min`` parameter was optional. The problem with ``{10}`` is the expression won't match if your search term is in the beginning of the text. Try this instead: ``{0,10}``.

Comment: No problem. Liked your one single simple regular expression. Thank you so much.